# How can I uninstall java from my Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall

When I write `java -version` in terminal it will displays following;

```
The program 'java' can be found in the following packages:

default-jre

 * gcj-4.8-jre-headless
 * openjdk-7-jre-headless
 * gcj-4.6-jre-headless
 * openjdk-6-jre-headless
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

How I uninstall the above java?

Answer (score 1):

Those packages are not yet installed. So, there's nothing to uninstall. You can install them if you want the `java` command.

Answer (score 1):

This actually shows that Java is not currently installed on your system. To install it, which I believe you should since it is used by many softwares:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install default-jre
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

To install the version distributed by Oracle, add the following PPA, The latest version is JDK 9

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java9-installer
```

To configure default Java version use:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```